# Unable to use .to() operator on Long data type

Tags: scala, for-loop, types, long-integer

The question is:
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

I have written a code for it but it gives an error.The code is written in Scala.

```
@main def m(): Unit = {
  var largest = 0L;
  val num = 600851475143L;
  2.to(num - 1).foreach(arg =>
    if num % arg == 0 && largest < arg then
      var flag = true;
      2.to(arg - 1).foreach(arg2 =>
        if arg % arg2 == 0 then flag = false);
      if flag then largest = arg;
  )
  println(largest);
}
```

The code gives an error of:
**Found:    Long
Required: Int
2.to(num - 1).foreach(arg =>**

How can we use .to() operator for Long datatype? It seems like we are only allowed to use Int.

I tried type casting the long to the Int but it resulted in the answer getting 0.

Comment: Change `2` to `2L`. Also remove the `;` this isn't Java. Overall this isn't very idiomatic Scala code. I recommend going through an introductory Scala course

Answer (score 4):

While number in a `Range` can be `Long`s, they cannot contain more than `Int.MaxValue` values ([docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.11/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html)):

> Any method that could require a collection of over `Int.MaxValue` length to be created, or could be asked to index beyond `Int.MaxValue` elements will throw an exception.

You can create a lazy `Iterator` that spans all numbers from `2L` to a `Long` greater than `Int.MaxValue` as follows:

```
Iterator.iterate(2L)(_ + 1).takeWhile(_ < max)
```

So in your code this would be the following:

```
@main def m(): Unit = {
  var largest = 0L;
  val num = 600851475143L;
  
  Iterator.iterate(2L)(_ + 1).takeWhile(_ < (num - 1)).foreach(arg =>
    if num % arg == 0 && largest < arg then
      var flag = true;
      Iterator.iterate(2L)(_ + 1).takeWhile(_ < (arg - 1)).foreach(arg2 =>
        if arg % arg2 == 0 then flag = false);
      if flag then largest = arg;
  )
  println(largest);
}
```

A few additional notes:

- you can drop the semicolons if you want, they are not needed in Scala
- producing the range lazily is a bit of a mouthful, it's probably best to give it a name
- you can use `for`-comprehensions as a way to express looping (what you are achieving with `foreach`)

Given this, one way to re-write your program could be the following:

```
def range(from: Long, to: Long, step: Long = 1) = {
  require(from < to)
  Iterator.iterate(from)(_ + step).takeWhile(_ < to)
}

var largest = 0L;
val num = 600851475143L;

for (arg <- range(from = 2L, to = num - 1)) {
  if num % arg == 0 && largest < arg then
    var flag = true
    for (arg2 <- range(from = 2L, to = arg - 1)) {
      if arg % arg2 == 0 then flag = false
    }
    if flag then largest = arg
}

println(largest)
```

The `for`-comprehension above is entirely equivalent to a `foreach`. They are particularly useful when you need to nest multiple `flatMap`s and close with a `map` or a `foreach` to make the code less nested and possibly easier to read. You can read more about them [in the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html).

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/W7KWGBOSQQSdb11ML7VGHg/10). Maybe consider giving your variables names more meaningful than `arg`, `arg2` and `flag` as well to improve the readability.

As a final note, more important than anything, your algorithm can probably be improved in terms of time complexity, but that's something you want to spent some time on by yourself. ;-)